# When I add the for() function, the other functions don't do anything in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create something where a function scans an array to get matching text. So basically, there is a for function, which scans a variable and sees if user input contains it.

```
var response = {
words : [
    {
        inputtext: "HI",
        output: "Hey There!"
    },
    {
        inputtext: "HELLO",
        output: "Hi!"
    },
    {
        inputtext: "GOOD",
        output: "That's nice!"
    },
    {
        inputtext: "HEY",
        output: "Hi!"
    },
    
],






//below are the phrases
phrases : [
        {
        inputtext: "WHAT CAN YOU DO",
        output: "You can try, give me a joke!"
    },
    {
        inputtext: "GIVE ME A JOKE",
        output: ["Maybe later.", "Okay!", "Soon."]
    },
    {
        inputtext: "YOU ARE MEAN",
        output: "Me? Mean? Think again!"
    },
            {
        inputtext: "HOW ARE YOU",
        output: "I'm good! How are you?"
    },
    {
        inputtext: "WHAT IS UP",
        output: "Nothing!"
    },
    {
        inputtext: "WHAT'S UP",
        output: "Nothing!"
    },
],
```

}

So it scans `response.words`, and sees the user input includes the `inputtext`, and if so, it tells you it's `output`. But I'm having some trouble with the scanning.

Everything is going fine with this code:

```js
var response = {
    words : [
        {
            inputtext: "HI",
            output: "Hey There!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "HELLO",
            output: "Hi!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "GOOD",
            output: "That's nice!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "HEY",
            output: "Hi!"
        },
        
    ],
    
    
    

    
    
    //below are the phrases
    phrases : [
            {
            inputtext: "WHAT CAN YOU DO",
            output: "You can try, give me a joke!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "GIVE ME A JOKE",
            output: ["Maybe later.", "Okay!", "Soon."]
        },
        {
            inputtext: "YOU ARE MEAN",
            output: "Me? Mean? Think again!"
        },
                {
            inputtext: "HOW ARE YOU",
            output: "I'm good! How are you?"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "WHAT IS UP",
            output: "Nothing!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "WHAT'S UP",
            output: "Nothing!"
        },
    ],
    
    
    
    
    
    
}


function scanreturn() {
          
    var str = document.getElementById("inputtextarea").value.toUpperCase();
    
        var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(str.includes(response.words[i].inputtext)) {
           alert(response.words[i].output)
        }
            
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="inputtextarea" onkeypress="enter()"></textarea>
        <button onclick="scanreturn()">Yes!</button>
        <p>Type "Hi", "Hello", "Good", or "Hey" in the textarea and press the "Yes!" button.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Don't mind the error(s).
But I need this to do something if it doesn't contain. If I try `else` on the `if ()`, I saw it did this:

```js
var response = {
    words : [
        {
            inputtext: "HI",
            output: "Hey There!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "HELLO",
            output: "Hi!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "GOOD",
            output: "That's nice!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "HEY",
            output: "Hi!"
        },
        
    ],
    
    
    

    
    
    //below are the phrases
    phrases : [
            {
            inputtext: "WHAT CAN YOU DO",
            output: "You can try, give me a joke!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "GIVE ME A JOKE",
            output: ["Maybe later.", "Okay!", "Soon."]
        },
        {
            inputtext: "YOU ARE MEAN",
            output: "Me? Mean? Think again!"
        },
                {
            inputtext: "HOW ARE YOU",
            output: "I'm good! How are you?"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "WHAT IS UP",
            output: "Nothing!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "WHAT'S UP",
            output: "Nothing!"
        },
    ],
    
    
    
    
    
    
}


function scanreturn() {
          
    var str = document.getElementById("inputtextarea").value.toUpperCase();
    
        var i;
    for (i = 0; i < response.words.length; i++) {
        if(str.includes(response.words[i].inputtext)) {
           alert(response.words[i].output)
        } else {
          alert("I don't understand.")
        }
            
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="inputtextarea" onkeypress="enter()"></textarea>
        <button onclick="scanreturn()">Yes!</button>
        <p>Type "Hi", "Hello", "Good", or "Hey" in the textarea and press the "Yes!" button.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also need it to scan `response.phrases` too. But if I duplicate the `for()` function, but change all the `response.words` to `response.phrases`, and instead of `alert()`-ing the `response.words/phrases[i].output`, I set a variable in the `scanreturn()` function, out the `for()` function though, to change when the `for()` loop function scanned a matching response. Like this:

```js
var response = {
    words : [
        {
            inputtext: "HI",
            output: "Hey There!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "HELLO",
            output: "Hi!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "GOOD",
            output: "That's nice!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "HEY",
            output: "Hi!"
        },
        
    ],
    
    
    

    
    
    //below are the phrases
    phrases : [
            {
            inputtext: "WHAT CAN YOU DO",
            output: "You can try, give me a joke!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "GIVE ME A JOKE",
            output: ["Maybe later.", "Okay!", "Soon."]
        },
        {
            inputtext: "YOU ARE MEAN",
            output: "Me? Mean? Think again!"
        },
                {
            inputtext: "HOW ARE YOU",
            output: "I'm good! How are you?"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "WHAT IS UP",
            output: "Nothing!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "WHAT'S UP",
            output: "Nothing!"
        },
    ],
    
    
    
    
    
    
}


function scanreturn() {
          
    var str = document.getElementById("inputtextarea").value.toUpperCase();
    var res;
        var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(str.includes(response.words[i].inputtext)) {
           res = response.words[i].output
        }
            
    }
  alert(res)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="inputtextarea" onkeypress="enter()"></textarea>
        <button onclick="scanreturn()">Yes!</button>
        <p>Type "Hi", "Hello", "Good", or "Hey" in the textarea and press the "Yes!" button.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then there, it doesn't `alert()` anything, even though it's set to `alert()` `res` after the `for()`, I believe the `res` variable is undefined.

Please show me how to fix this problem, also, I think `localStorage()` will work, I think I tried one time, but it didn't fix it, I really think that should fix it so maybe I did it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a counter to return how many times the word is found. like this:

JavaScript:

```
var response = {
    words : [
        {
            inputtext: "HI",
            output: "Hey There!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "HELLO",
            output: "Hi!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "GOOD",
            output: "That's nice!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "HEY",
            output: "Hi!"
        },
        
    ],
    
    
    

    
    
    //below are the phrases
    phrases : [
            {
            inputtext: "WHAT CAN YOU DO",
            output: "You can try, give me a joke!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "GIVE ME A JOKE",
            output: ["Maybe later.", "Okay!", "Soon."]
        },
        {
            inputtext: "YOU ARE MEAN",
            output: "Me? Mean? Think again!"
        },
                {
            inputtext: "HOW ARE YOU",
            output: "I'm good! How are you?"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "WHAT IS UP",
            output: "Nothing!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "WHAT'S UP",
            output: "Nothing!"
        },
    ],
    
}

function scanreturn() {
  var str = document.getElementById("inputtextarea").value.toUpperCase();
  var i;
  var results = 0;
  var len = Object.keys(response.words).length;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if(str.includes(response.words[i].inputtext)) {
      let out = response.words[i].output;
      if (out) {
        alert(out);
        results++;
      }
    }
  }
  if (results == 0) { alert("I don't understand.") }
}
```

I also added the `Object.keys(response.words).length` to calc how many informations have.

you can check the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fcvhzroq/3/

**EDIT**

In order to envolve the phrases, there's a complement of the code using the same idea:

```
var response = {
    words : [
        {
            inputtext: "HI",
            output: "Hey There!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "HELLO",
            output: "Hi!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "GOOD",
            output: "That's nice!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "HEY",
            output: "Hi!"
        },
        
    ],
    
    
    

    
    
    //below are the phrases
    phrases : [
            {
            inputtext: "WHAT CAN YOU DO",
            output: "You can try, give me a joke!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "GIVE ME A JOKE",
            output: ["Maybe later.", "Okay!", "Soon."]
        },
        {
            inputtext: "YOU ARE MEAN",
            output: "Me? Mean? Think again!"
        },
                {
            inputtext: "HOW ARE YOU",
            output: "I'm good! How are you?"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "WHAT IS UP",
            output: "Nothing!"
        },
        {
            inputtext: "WHAT'S UP",
            output: "Nothing!"
        },
    ],
    
}

function scanreturn() {
  var str = document.getElementById("inputtextarea").value.toUpperCase();
  var i;
  var results = 0;
  var len = Object.keys(response.words).length;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if(str.includes(response.words[i].inputtext)) {
      let out = response.words[i].output;
      if (out) {
        alert(out);
        results++;
      }
    }
  }
  if (results == 0) {
    var i;
    var len = Object.keys(response.phrases).length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if(str.includes(response.phrases[i].inputtext)) {
        let out = response.phrases[i].output;
        if (out) {
          alert(out);
          results++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (results == 0) {
    alert("I don't understand.");
  }
}
```

As you can see in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xjohnatha/28nzd40v/4/

And answering the comment you left, in this code the search for phrases come after the words. This way won't be any duplicates. However, unlikely you said, the search will use the entire value on the input, not the first letter, then the second, etc. Unless the `enter()` function do that, but you didn't put this is on the question.

Comment: So for the phrases, if I want it to scan the phrases too after it scans the words (which I specifically want the words to be scanned before the. phrases, let's say there is a word called "how", and a phrase "how are you", if it scanned the phrases first, then the word "how" would overwrite the phrase "how are you"), do I dulicate anything?

Comment: I'll edit the answer to envolve the phrases too

Comment: Please, if this answer your question right, I'll ask you to set that as the solution

Comment: Also, I will make a variable called `response.statements`, each one in that will look like this: {statement: function() {  return something() }  }, so if I do that, how would it scan the statements after the phrases and the phrases always return something, like if you said `add 2 plus 5`, then it returns the value of that when it calculates it, if you know what I mean, like the phrases, except the `inputtext` is a function that returns something, how would I do that?

Comment: also, what does `Object.keys(response.words).length ` mean?

Comment: Sorry, but I have a few more questions. I think that if it finds a word and a phrase that matches, then the word will overwrite the phrase, but I want the phrases to overwrite the words.

Comment: If you want it to calc the statement, I believe that you can do it in JavaScript, like `var str = "add 2 plus 5"; var strs = str.split(" "); var calc = 0; if ((strs[0] == 'add') && (strs[2] == 'plus')) { calc = Number(strs[1]) + Number(strs[3]); results++; } alert("That's easy: " + calc);` This code split the var by blank space and create a list that you can use in your conditions for calc. But you need to put it before the condition "i dont understand". The `str = "add 2 plus 5";` is for test, you can remove when you paste on your code.

Comment: `Object.keys(response.words).length` serves to calc how many items you have in the list you made. These are not strings, it creates Objects.

Comment: In this code, there's no way to overwrite, because you have to write the sentence like it is in the variable. The frases will only return if you put the complete sentence in the input. The phrase "WHAT CAN YOU DO" will not return if you put only "WHAT", or "WHAT CAN".

Comment: What I'm trying to say, is if there's a word and a phrase that match at the same time, it will return the word, so I want it to return the phrases if there is a matching word **and** phrase. Let's say there is a word "HOW", and that returns "Okay!", then there is a phrase named "HOW ARE YOU", and it returns "Good". So if I typed "How are you?", that contains the word "HOW" and the phrase "HOW ARE YOU", so then it will return the word. But I want it to return the phrase if the user types something that has a phrase and a word, and not returning the word's `output`.

Comment: I understand you. This will only happen if the word is the same of phrase. And will not happen. Just if you put word "HOW" and phrase "HOW". this code does not scan for words or letters, this code match the exactly sentence.

Comment: If you still want to make sure that it won't happen, you can move the phrases block of codes in JS before the block of codes of words.

Comment: I have another question, I tried to add to `response`, `response.statements`, then I try to get it to scan that, but if I test out the statements, it says it doesn't understand. I am not sure why it does this. You can see in JSFiddle here what I mean : https://jsfiddle.net/WildandRare/fqdpucar/6/

Comment: You were going in a right way. But when you want to split a string, you have to put the char that separates it. In your case, is the white/blank space. So you need to use `var res = calculate.split(" ")[1];` . Another thing to ajust is the inputtext. In the code you put it to match into uppercase, so you need to set in the statements: ` inputtext: "SAY" `. I ajust the output of statement to return only first letter uppercase, otherwise the return will be all uppercase. Check it out: [https://jsfiddle.net/xjohnatha/mj3guzqv/13/](https://jsfiddle.net/xjohnatha/mj3guzqv/13/)